# Query to order parent/child-hierachy

Tags: mysql

There's a table I have now:

[image]

I can't think of a query that would make the order of 'name' column that i need.

I need it to go like this:
`ads->work_and_business->search_work->require_work->freelance->transport->cars->trucks->water->air->...`

so, basically i need like parent->all children, next parent->all children

can someone help with this?

Edit: table create script:

```
CREATE TABLE categories ( 
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  level int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1', 
  parent_category_id int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1', 
  name varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (id), 
  KEY FK_categories_categories (parent_category_id)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Edit2: level is needed for something else in php part. in query part it's not needed

Comment: Can you please do `show create table tblname` and paste results versus a picture somewhere

Comment: CREATE TABLE `categories` (  
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  `level` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',  
  `parent_category_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',  
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),  
  KEY `FK_categories_categories` (`parent_category_id`)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Comment: @La7v1aN Instead of posting a comment you can (and should) use the edit function instead and add the new information to the question. I did it for you now.

Comment: `level` column isn't really needed is it

Answer (score 0):

I tried with your sample data and i think this works

```
SELECT distinct(ifnull(c1.name,c.name)) as name 
from categories c 
right JOIN categories c1 ON c.id=c1.parent_category_id 
order by c.parent_category_id;
```